# Error Add Class from another project in the same solutions C++

Tags: c++, reference, c++-cx

I'm just beginning to write code with C++, and I got stuck when I want to add reference to class from other project from the same solutions.
my Main code located at :

1. InventoryAppDLL (contains code to access Sql Database)
2. class : dbConnection.h
3. Code:

   ```
   ref class dbConnection
   {
   public:
       dbConnection();
       void SetCommandText(String ^command,bool ^commandText);
       int ExecuteScalar();
       DataSet^ ExecuteDataSet();
       DataTable^ ExecuteDataTable();
   protected:
        ~dbConnection();

   private:
        DbConnection ^conn;
        DbCommand ^cmd;
        ConnectionStringSettings ^settings;
        DbProviderFactory ^fac;
   };
   ```

   after i build the main project (InventoryAppDLL), it was success and contains no errors.

but after I include the header into another project (InventoryAppService),and then I build it, it contains error :

```
    error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '^'
```

when I reference to the error,  I've got ConnectionStringSettings missing library on dbConnectionClass (InventoryAppDLL).

```
    private:
         DbConnection ^conn;
         DbCommand ^cmd;
         ConnectionStringSettings ^settings; // <---
         DbProviderFactory ^fac;
    };
```

Comment: Could be stupid question..  But did you include .h file for included class in your file?

Comment: yupz..I add dbConnection.h in my project(InventoryAppService). And also I follow other answer from another post to add class from other projects from the same solutions(from project properties).

Comment: C++/CX (Windows Runtime)

Comment: is ^ a valid reference symbol in C++?

Comment: @Raja: No; it's part of C++/CX

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't even need to include the header file.  Since you have already added a reference from the consuming project to the project containing this class, the consuming project can read the metadata from the DLL project and you can simply say:

```
auto x = ref new dbConnection();
```

Comment: You still need a visible declaration, no?

Comment: What kind of declaration?  Adding the reference sets up the consuming project to just start using the types from the DLL project.  No #include or #import required in source.

Comment: Then C++/CX is even less like C++ than I thought.